# Looking for a dax function to create an insight to shows all duplicates based on multiple criteria

Tags: duplicates, powerbi, dax

I'm trying to develop a calculated field within a powerbi report and more importantly an output that I can make into an insight that shows duplicate accounts , that are created with data with criteria matching in multiple columns. For example, give me all accounts that have the same following: Client Name, Provider Name, Date of service, time beginning, time ending, and procedure code. To clarify, there are duplicate accounts in my system due to user error generating more than once, but they do not have the same account number. Too many clients and providers to spell out all the names, so need it to calculate based on what's in each column.

count rows, calculate withing power query editor and in the modeling screen. I run into a ton of token literal errors, and token comma expected errors. When I get no exceptions, it doesn't recognize the expression and doesn't load.

```
countifs=calculate(
countrows ( Table ),
    filter (
        table,
        table[Client Name] = [Client Name]
            & table[Provider Name] = [Provider Name]&[Date Of Service]=[Date Of Service]&[Time started]=[Time started]&[Time ended]=[Time ended]&[billing_codes_and_labels.code]=[billing_codes_and_labels.code]
    )
)
```

I'm looking to grab all duplicate accounts according to the user who's creating for them to be able to delete the duplicate accounts in the system. It will be a matrix report with splicers on each user. The unique values are going to have an output of more than 1, of which this is what the user will be focused on.

Answer (score 1):

With variables, the duplicate count is much cleaner than using the EARLIER function (which was used before there was variable in Power BI). Please see:

```
countifs =
VAR cName = 'table'[Client Name]
VAR pName = 'table'[Provider Name]
VAR dService = 'table'[Date Of Service]
VAR tStarted = 'table'[Time started]
VAR tEnd = 'table'[Time ended]
VAR bCode = 'table'[billing_codes_and_labels.code]
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( 'table' ),
        FILTER (
            'table',
            'table'[Client Name] = cName
                && 'table'[Provider Name] = pName
                && 'table'[Date Of Service] = dService
                && 'table'[Time started] = tStarted
                && 'table'[Time ended] = tEnd
                && 'table'[billing_codes_and_labels.code] = bCode
        )
    )
```

Thanks